# input button not getting set in the POST variable

Tags: php

I have a page with two forms.  I need to know which button is submitting the form.  When the form gets submitted I am checking the set status of the button, but it doesn't seem to be set.  Can anyone help?

HTML

```
<div id="contact-wrapper" class="">                
    <h1 style="color: white">Send me an email.</h1>
    <div id="msg-status"></div>
    <form id="contact" method="post">
        <div class="contact-title">Email Address</div>
        <input type="email" name="emailAddress" id="email-addr-txt"  placeholder="Your Email Address" require>
        <div class="contact-title">Subject</div>
        <input type="text" name="emailSubject" id="email-subject-txt"  placeholder="Subject" require>
        <div class="contact-title">Message</div>                    
        <textarea name="emailMessage" id="email-msg-txt"  placeholder="Message" require></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="sendBtn" value="Send" id="send-msg-btn">
    </form>
</div>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $phpconsole = "";
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
        if (isset($_POST["loginBtn"])) {
            //Do Stuff
        }
        if (isset($_POST["sendBtn"])) {
            //Do Stuff
        }
        $phpconsole = var_dump($_POST);    }    
?>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#contact').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    email_regex = /^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i;
    var msg = "";
    if ($('#email-addr-txt').val() == ""){
        msg += "<p>The email address is missing!</p>";
    } else if (!email_regex.test($('#email-addr-txt').val())) {
        msg += "<p>The email address is invalid!</P>"
    }

    if ($('#email-subject-txt').val() == "") {
        msg += "<p>The Subject is missing!</p>";
    }

    if ($('#email-msg-txt').val() == "") {
        msg += "<p>The message is missing!</p>"
    }

    var heightOfContactWrapper = $('#contact-wrapper').height();
    if (msg != "") { // There were errors that need to be delt with before sending message.
        msg = "<h2>There were errors.</h2>" + msg;
        $('#msg-status').html(msg);
        $('#msg-status').addClass('msg-status-fail');
        
        var heightOfMsgStatus = $('#msg-status').height() + $('#contact-wrapper').height() + "px";
        $('#contact-wrapper').css('height', (heightOfContactWrapper + $('#msg-status').height() + "px"));
    } else { //No errors found.
        $('#msg-status').removeClass('msg-status-fail');
        $('#msg-status').addClass('msg-status-success');
        $('#msg-status').html("<h2>Message is sending.  Please wait.</h2>")
        $('#contact-wrapper').css('height', (heightOfContactWrapper + $('#msg-status').height() + "px"));
        $('#contact').unbind('submit').submit();
    }
});
```

Output of var_dump is

> array(3) { ["emailAddress"]=> string(13) "asdf@aedf.com"
> ["emailSubject"]=> string(4) "asdf" ["emailMessage"]=> string(4)
> "asdf" }

Errors are:

> Notice: Undefined index: loginBtn in /var/www/new-site/index.php on
> line 5 Notice: Undefined index: SendBtn in /var/www/new-site/index.php
> on line 5

Comment: no errors occure? or anything message did you var_dump your Post?

Comment: Just use `if (isset($_POST["loginBtn"])){ //-->logic to run if true  }`. What do you get on a  `var_dump` for $_POST?

Comment: Your `var_dump` has fields that aren't in the form you've included in your question (e.g. `emailSubject`). Could you paste the actual form code you're using?

Comment: @Cully Sorry about that.  I put the correct code in there.

Comment: I just put your form code in a PHP file with a `var_dump($POST)` at the top. submitted the empty form, and got this output: `array(4) { ["emailAddress"]=> string(0) "" ["emailSubject"]=> string(0) "" ["emailMessage"]=> string(0) "" ["sendBtn"]=> string(4) "Send" }`

Comment: Could it be because of this line $('#contact').unbind('submit').submit();

Comment: Oh, I realized what the issue is. I'll post an answer.

Comment: FYI You should be using `<label>`s for your form labels, not `<div>`s.

Comment: @user229044  I do plan to change that.  One of those for later changes.  Thanks for pointing it out though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your Javascript code ends up being the thing that triggers the form submit, not your button. If you removed your JS code you'd see your `sendBtn` value.

Instead of calling `e.preventDefault` in your `.submit()` callback, you could just return true if you want the form submission to continue, or false if you don't. That way, you don't have to call `$('#contact').submit()` to get your form to submit, or even unbind your submit handler. Something like this:

```js
$('#contact').submit(function(e){
    email_regex = /^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i;
    var msg = "";
    if ($('#email-addr-txt').val() == ""){
        msg += "<p>The email address is missing!</p>";
    } else if (!email_regex.test($('#email-addr-txt').val())) {
        msg += "<p>The email address is invalid!</P>"
    }

    if ($('#email-subject-txt').val() == "") {
        msg += "<p>The Subject is missing!</p>";
    }

    if ($('#email-msg-txt').val() == "") {
        msg += "<p>The message is missing!</p>"
    }

    var heightOfContactWrapper = $('#contact-wrapper').height();
    if (msg != "") { // There were errors that need to be delt with before sending message.
        msg = "<h2>There were errors.</h2>" + msg;
        $('#msg-status').html(msg);
        $('#msg-status').addClass('msg-status-fail');
        
        var heightOfMsgStatus = $('#msg-status').height() + $('#contact-wrapper').height() + "px";
        $('#contact-wrapper').css('height', (heightOfContactWrapper + $('#msg-status').height() + "px"));
        return false;
    } else { //No errors found.
        $('#msg-status').removeClass('msg-status-fail');
        $('#msg-status').addClass('msg-status-success');
        $('#msg-status').html("<h2>Message is sending.  Please wait.</h2>")
        $('#contact-wrapper').css('height', (heightOfContactWrapper + $('#msg-status').height() + "px"));
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh, I think it's because the submit event isn't unbound immediately. I have a better solution, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @TimNeufeld I updated my answer with a better way of solving this.

Comment: @TimNeufeld I added your PHP code into a test file and it runs for me. Also, if I `var_dump($POST)` I see the submit button value.

Comment: I used setTimeout to run the click 100ms after the unbind.  That seems to have solved the issue.  I wonder if this will cause issues later on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222469/discussion-between-tim-neufeld-and-cully).

Comment: That's a way fo getting around the problem of the `submit` even not being unbound immediately. Though it's not a great idea to use `setTimeout` to solve issues like that. It's potentially unpredictable.